# Void pointer cast to long double gives garbage

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have made a basic function which uses a void pointer and then handles the input based on its type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int writeVal (int id, void *ptr, int byteSize)
{
    printf ("size is %d" , byteSize);
    if (byteSize == sizeof(int))
    {
    printf("int %d", *(int*)ptr);
    }
    if (byteSize == sizeof(float))
    {
        printf("float  %f", *(float*)ptr);
    }
    if (byteSize == sizeof(double))
    {
    printf("double %lf", *(double*)ptr);
    }
    if (byteSize == sizeof(long double))
    {
    printf("long double %lf", *(long double*)ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Unknown Type");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    long double i=30.0;
    long double *ff=&i;
    int ret=writeVal(10, ff,sizeof(*ff));

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for all values except when I pass a long double, in which case it gives out a garbage value. Why is this happening?

Secondly, is this the best way to deal with a pointer holding data whose type can be anything?

Comment: Does it print "long double" before the garbage?

Comment: Yes it does print long double.

Comment: @Isaiah what method do you recommend then, to have a function where any data type can be passed, and it must be able to print it and do other operations?

Comment: I was just noting the fact that the standard makes few guarantees on pointer casts, but the answer given seem to be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format specifier for a `long double` is `%Lf` (uppercase L), not `%lf`.

```
printf("long double %Lf", *(long double*)ptr);
//                   ^ here
```